What is Baudelaire's poem "Allégorie" an allegory of?
In his collection Les Fleurs du Mal (1857), Charles Baudelaire wrote a poem called "Allégorie". The poem begins:

C'est une femme belle, et de riche encolure
Qui laisse dans son vin traîner sa chevelure.
Les griffes de l’amour, les poisons du tripot,
Tout glisse et tout s’émousse au granit de sa peau.

The 1906 translation by Frank Pearce Sturm begins:

Here is a woman, richly clad and fair,
Who in her wine dips her long, heavy hair;
Love's claws, and that sharp poison which is sin,
Are dulled against the granite of her skin.

I have not been able to find anywhere an explanation of this poem stating of what, exactly, the character depicted in this poem was supposed to be an allegory.

The title might suggest a subversion of the concept of allegory itself - see https://books.openedition.org/puse/3212?lang=en#anchor-toc-1-1
